# Why are random spaces being removed from Dynamics 365 Email messages?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

This issue is difficult to reproduce because it seems to happen intermittently.

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics 365. I'm generating emails using the default Email Message entity by populating the description with the required content.

The problem I'm having is that *sometimes*, after saving and closing the edit window, the spaces between some words seem to get removed. When I open the editor again I see there are lots of spaces missing through seemingly random parts of the email's body.

I know there are third party tools available for sending and generating emails using Dynamics or Azure but unfortunately in this particular case I'm unable to utilize them. The solution is restricted to functionality built into Dynamics 365.

*Example email before save:*

> Hi {Contact(Full Name)},
>
> Welcome to the team!

*Example email after save:*

> Hi {Contact(Full Name)},
>
> Welcome tothe team!

Comment: Need some sample data or screenshot to understand

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an issue I can provide example data for or even more useful reproduction steps due to the intermittent nature of the problem. I'm hoping someone has experienced the same problem and can share their solution or workaround.

Comment: Whenever intermittently issue happens take some screenshot & share..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I've added a basic example, however unless this is a problem you recognise because you've seen it before, I don't think the example will be particularly useful.

Comment: how are you populating the description from the required content & from where? form scripting or plugin?

Comment: Neither Form or Plugin. I'm using the out of the box Send Email workflow activity. And using the standard form to populate the description field.